# How to reduce the gaps between words in a reference entry

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using the Easy Thesis template to write my thesis. I find one of my reference entry contain huge gaps between the words. [image: This picture shows the gaps between words].

I am using `natbib` bibliography style. How I can reduce or condense the empty gap between words?

Comment: Are you using `natbib` with `bibtex` or `biblatex`? I thinks there is a mistake with your tags. In the other hand, do you use a package for control the hyphenation of your urls? I thinks that's the source of the error as your image don't show another entry without urls and bad justificated.

Comment: URLs are bad news for good line breaks in justified text.  In this case, the problem is exacerbated by the long-phrase-in-hyphens: while TeX does not like to break words with hyphens due to the potential resulting ambiguity, the `url` package (by default) *really* doesn't like to do it.

Comment: Did you try loading the `url` package with the option `hyphens`?

Comment: Dear Aradnix, I am using natbib with bibtex. Also I dont using any "url" package. Is any url package can justify the spaces between the words?

Comment: Dear Mico, I just tried with 'url' package. There is no any improvement.

Comment: @Vijay - Did you load the `url` package with the option `hyphens`?

Comment: try `/usepackage[hyphens]{url}` in case you didnt know how

Comment: since I am using \usepackage{hyperref}, when I use /usepackage[hyphens]{url}, it conflicts.

Comment: The `url` package (with the `hyphens` option) must be loaded *before* `hyperref`.

Comment: I did soemthing like this. \usepackage{url} and fowllowed by 

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

Comment: If you're going to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`, that command has to come _before_ you load the package in question. In this case, I'd think it easier to simply use `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`.

Comment: @Vijay could you please add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us and faster for you to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It's a little bit annoying to have to suggest something blindly without a concrete example and no code to analyze.

Comment: To me, the obvious thing to do is to typeset the bibliography ragged right instead of justified. Try inserting `\raggedright` at the appropriate point.

Comment: Are there any news here?